# How to find the total spendings in a restaurant when it is given as a system of equations using exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The problem is as follows:

Jenny goes to dinner to a well known restaurant in town. The number of times she goes to the restaurant is $\frac{a}{2}$ times and for each time she went, she spent $b^{2}$ hundreds of dollars. Find the money Jenny spent assuming the following system of equations was observed by Jenny.

$$\begin{cases}
3^a-2^{b^{2}}=77 \\ 
3^{\frac{a}{2}}-2^{\frac{b^2}{2}}=7 \\ 
\end{cases}$$

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{600 dollars}\\
2.&\textrm{500 dollars}\\
3.&\textrm{400 dollars}\\
4.&\textrm{300 dollars}\\
\end{array}$

In this given situation the only thing which I can understand is as this:

$\textrm{Money spent}=\frac{a}{2}\cdot b^2\cdot 10^2$

But the thing is how to find $a$ and $b$, which sort of simplication or algebraic manipulation can be done to solve this system of equation.

Can someone help me?.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

We have

$$3^a-2^{b^2}=77$$

and

$$3^{\frac{a}2}-2^{\frac{b^2}2}=7$$

Dividing the equations, we get

$$3^{\frac{a}2}+2^{\frac{b^2}2}=11$$

Now, solve a linear system equation to solve for $3^\frac{a}2$ and $2^\frac{b^2}2$.

Comment: I think **the problem here is how to divide those two equations** can you include these?. I'm stuck at **how you did that**?. Please, I'm stuck.

Comment: We use the identity $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$. Dividing $x^2-y^2$ with $x-y$ gives us $x+y$. Try to identify the $x$ and $y$ here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 3^a$ and $y = 2^{b^2}$
Therefore, $x   = 77+y$   (as $x-y = 77$)
and, $\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{y} + 7$  (as $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} = 7$)
Squaring the second and subtractiing from the first we have,
$0 =28-14\sqrt{y}$
Therefore, $y = 4$ and $x=81$
So $a =4$ and $b^2 =2$
The answer is 400